# Windows Metro Style app occur error with Google Data API Library

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, google-docs-api

OS: Windows 8 Consumer Preview
IDE: Visual Studio 11 Beta

I create a Blank Application(Windows Metro style).
And add Google Doc API sample code. (It is below)
It occur compile Error.(**Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter in module System.dll**)

But When I create a Console Application(Windows), don't occur compile Error and Google Doc API working good.

Any ideas?

```
using System;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Documents;

namespace MyDocumentsListIntegration
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService("MyDocumentsListIntegration-v1");

      // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see Authorizing requests)

      // Instantiate a DocumentsListQuery object to retrieve documents.
      DocumentsListQuery query = new DocumentsListQuery();

      // Make a request to the API and get all documents.
      DocumentsFeed feed = service.Query(query);

      // Iterate through all of the documents returned
      foreach (DocumentEntry entry in feed.Entries)
      {
        // Print the title of this document to the screen
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Argh, I have the same issue... Really need the Google API for a Metro app... How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the [ExpandableObjectConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter.aspx) class exists in the standard .NET framework, but if you look at the Metro API documentation for [System.ComponentModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454035%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace, that class is not listed and so is not available.

I recommend using the [.NET for Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page to discover what is available when writing a Metro style application.