# Rotate bitmapImage in windows store app

Tags: c#, .net, image, windows-store-apps, transformation

trying to rotate a bitmapImage 90 degrees but have been unable so far.

this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.rotation(v=vs.110).aspx#feedback

doesn't actually work.
TransformedBitmap type does not exist and and BitmapImage has no .beginInit() and .EndInit() methods

I already have added

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
```

have MS forgot to update their documentation, am I doing something wrong or is this actually not meant for Windows 8?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform.aspx
I also found this but were unable to find an example of using it.

Comment: did you checked this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709937.aspx?

Comment: Implemented and runs, but been unable to get it actually to rotate the image. it looks like the right stuff though.

Comment: if is working I will posted like an answer. I did not have time to test it yet.

Comment: The solution looks legit like I said, but sadly can't say that it has worked for me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709937.aspx

this as suggested by Mihai Hantea ended up doing the trick. Turns out I was missing an Await command on a .FlushAsync(). After addding the await it suddenly came together and worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 1):

The TransformedBitmap type does exist. But you have to add a reference to you project to `PresentationCore.dll`

Then follow this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970271(v=vs.110).aspx

(Stolen from the link)

```
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Water Lilies.jpg");

myBitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
myBitmapImage.EndInit();

TransformedBitmap myRotatedBitmapSource = new TransformedBitmap();

myRotatedBitmapSource.BeginInit();

myRotatedBitmapSource.Source = myBitmapImage;

myRotatedBitmapSource.Transform = new RotateTransform(90);
myRotatedBitmapSource.EndInit()
```

Comment: did this, and also referenced WindowsBase as required.
beginInit and endInit are still not being found and furthermore after changing to x86 architecture as required by the added references I now get 
   cannot find type System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter in module System.dll

which seems to be related to the fact that it does not exist for store apps as described here (next comment)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509955/windows-metro-style-app-occur-error-with-google-data-api-library

Comment: That is wierd. I tried it and it worked just fine. Only needed these usings `using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;`

Comment: I am not. But if my answers didnt help im afraid I cant help you anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help in your situation:

Code-Behind:

```
var image = new Image
                    { 
                        Height = 50,
                        Width = 50,
                        RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() 
                        { 
                        Angle = 90, 
                        CenterX = 25, //The prop name maybe mistyped 
                        CenterY =25 //The prop name maybe mistyped 
                        },
                        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("MyImageSoruce"))
                    };

MainGrid.Children.Add(image);
```

Comment: that would probably solve the issue of rotating the image for displaying but since I need to save the rotated BitmapImage (that is the C# type) after being rotated it's not a solution :(

Comment: I Got it, i know its hack, but what if you rotate the image and save it into a file with cropping? :D