# Xamarin Form - How to upload,Delete,Download Files From Google Drive in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

Hello friend I want to upload an images,files on Google Drive. So I have installed the `Google.Apis.Auth` and `Google.Apis.Drive.v3` nuget packages.

I have also created the  `Client_secrete.json` file by referring video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtqpWG5KDXYNow`. Question, how to use this `Client_secrete.json` file and upload, download, delete the files from the Google Drive in `uwp` ? :(

Any idea then please share code or link.

Thanks in advance :)...

```
  public static DriveService GetService()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        DriveService service = new DriveService();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(destinationFolder.Path + @"\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            String FolderPath = destinationFolder.Path;
            String FilePath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, 
"DriveServiceCredentials.json");
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "users",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(FilePath, true)).Result;   // Here i got 
the exception.

            service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "DemoDrive",
            });

        }
        return service;

    }
```

When i am trying to run this code it gives error. :( how to solve this.....

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check  [`Google.Apis.Drive.v3`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/), the nuget package incompatible platform contain uwp and Xamarin. So, you could not use it for xamarin.uwp app. For cloud drive within uwp platform, we suggest you use [**OneDrive**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/?view=odsp-graph-online) to replace. And we have provide [OneDrive Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive) api that could implement cloud drive immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/blob/master/OAuthUniversalApp/README.md) then what is the use of this google Oath sample ? what if i want to store my data on google drive ? is their any third party dll ?

Comment: @ketan, This case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39760255/7254781) may helpful.

Comment: OneDrive support for the UWP windows app ? if support then please share some code or links. which nuget package should i install ?  thank you :)

Comment: Please check this code sample [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive#sample-code). Please install   [`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/) nuget package.

Comment: do you have any other code sample i don't understand the above link :(

Comment: i have downloaded the uwp sample project form given [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows) but i don't how its works do you have an idea.

Comment: do you have any idea ?

Comment: Please try to run this uwp [project](https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthUniversalApp).

Comment: i am not getting how to set the redirectUrl ? where is it ? i have followed every steps but where is the redirect url ?

Comment: sorry man, currently, google production  is not in our support scope.

Comment: you mean to say i cant implement this project logic into my uwp application ?

Comment: I mean I have not used this sample, So I could not explain `redirectUrl` clearly.