# UWP / C# SDK to connect multiple cloud services

Tags: c#, uwp, sdk, cloud-storage

I am looking for a third-party library that allows me to connect to multiple cloud storage services like:

- Google Drive
- Box
- OneDrive
- DropBox
- iCloud

etc.

I can obviously use the single SDKs available for the single providers, but in this case I need to implement all the different workflows to authenticate, etc.

I am looking for an easy SDK that enables the integration of all these services, so that the user can connect her own accounts, providing obviously her credentials.

Comment: I highly suspect there is something like that right now.

Comment: Thanks @AVK , do you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: this will helps you a lot follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56287454/11362349) because there is no any third party dll which provide this all services in uwp