# Google Drive API in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, google-drive-api

I looked for a solution in Google about using Google Drive API in UWP.
I saw [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734307/using-google-drive-net-api-with-uwp-app), and the accepted solution is short - doesn't work as it is in UWP apps.

I tried to create a new class and it did work.

```
//StorageFile tempfile = Credentials location
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(tempfile.Path)
.CreateScoped(new[] { DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveFile });

var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "App name"
});
```

after that, I could use Drive API to upload and download. All I needed to do - was make everything as Task.

For example -

```
using (var stream = tempfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync().Result)
{
    var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "application/octet-stream");
    request.Upload();

    var uploadedFile = request.ResponseBody;
    Debug.WriteLine($"File uploaded: {uploadedFile.Name} ({uploadedFile.Id})");
}
```

I used `.Result` and `.AsTask().Wait()` instead of `await` and `AsTask().Result` in any function.
Did it work only in debug? or now it supports?

sorry about my English

Comment: Never used UWP, so no idea if that will cause any issues, but I [wrote a package](https://github.com/MrYossu/Pixata.Utilities/tree/master/Pixata.Google) to ease the (considerable) pain when using Google Drive.  There's a Nuget package available for it. Maybe see if that helps.

Comment: The Google API dotnet client library doesn't support up authorization

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo well, I just succeeded in uploading a file and downloading it in UWP and google.drive.api.v3

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel this package work on uwp?

Comment: @ArielP As I said in my comment, I've never used UWP, so can't say for definite. However, it's basically plain .NET, so no real reason why not. The only issue is that the current version assumes the credentials are in a specific file, which is based around AS.NET Core. I have a fix so that you can load credentials from anywhere, but haven't had time to test and publish it. You might need to play with that bit, but once you've got the credentials loaded, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work in any kind of .NET project